# Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause

Tags: group-by

i am getting error on my grouping... please help. my SQL code is below. i am trying to get 1 column of doctor name, 2 column medicare patients count, 3 column NON medicare patients

```
SELECT DoctorListName,
(CASE WHEN InsuranceCarrierName IN ('Humana Medicare','Medicare','Humana Gold Plus Medicare')
THEN count(uvPatientInsurance.InsuranceCarrierName) END) as CountMedicare,
(CASE WHEN InsuranceCarrierName NOT IN ('Humana Medicare','Medicare','Humana Gold Plus Medicare')
THEN count(uvPatientInsurance.InsuranceCarrierName) END) as CountNOTMedicare

FROM (STPN.dbo.vSelectPatient vSelectPatient
INNER JOIN STPN.dbo.uvPatientInsurance uvPatientInsurance ON vSelectPatient.PatientId=uvPatientInsurance.PatientId)
INNER JOIN STPN.dbo.uvVisit uvVisit ON vSelectPatient.PatientId=uvVisit.PatientId

WHERE vSelectPatient.PatientStatusMId=-900
AND (uvVisit.Entered>={ts '2011-01-01 00:00:00'}
AND uvVisit.Entered<{ts '2012-09-30 00:00:01'})
GROUP BY DoctorListName,
(CASE WHEN InsuranceCarrierName IN ('Humana Medicare','Medicare','Humana Gold Plus Medicare')
THEN count(uvPatientInsurance.InsuranceCarrierName) END),
(CASE WHEN InsuranceCarrierName NOT IN ('Humana Medicare','Medicare','Humana Gold Plus Medicare')
 THEN count(uvPatientInsurance.InsuranceCarrierName) END)
```

Comment: Which SQL? TSQL, PLSQL or MySQL?

Comment: @user1774975: Then please clarify your question and post the answer so that it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, when using `COUNT` or any aggregate function, you need to specify a `GROUP BY` clause...just like the error says:

```
SELECT DoctorListName,
(CASE WHEN InsuranceCarrierName IN ('Humana Medicare','Medicare','Humana Gold Plus  Medicare')
THEN count(uvPatientInsurance.InsuranceCarrierName) END) as CountMedicare,
(CASE WHEN InsuranceCarrierName NOT IN ('Humana Medicare','Medicare','Humana Gold Plus Medicare')
THEN count(uvPatientInsurance.InsuranceCarrierName) END) as CountNOTMedicare

FROM (STPN.dbo.vSelectPatient vSelectPatient
INNER JOIN STPN.dbo.uvPatientInsurance uvPatientInsurance ON vSelectPatient.PatientId=uvPatientInsurance.PatientId)
INNER JOIN STPN.dbo.uvVisit uvVisit ON vSelectPatient.PatientId=uvVisit.PatientId

WHERE vSelectPatient.PatientStatusMId=-900
AND (uvVisit.Entered>={ts '2011-01-01 00:00:00'}
AND uvVisit.Entered<{ts '2012-09-30 00:00:01'})
GROUP BY DoctorListName
```

Your `GROUP BY` clause can only use columns, no aggregate functions like `COUNT`.